# pg_dump, dump options "pre-data", What are the "data definition items" included in "pre_data"?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am reading the [doc of PG Admin 4 about backup dialog box which uses the `pg_dump` utility](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/backup_dialog.html).

In the **dump options** tab, there is a sub-menu **Section** with three switches.

One of the switch is named "pre-data" and the doc explains:

> Move the switch next to Pre-data to the Yes position to include all data definition items not included in the data or post-data item lists.

I don't understand what is included in:

> all data definition items not included in the data or post-data item lists.

**What are those "data definition items" included in "pre data"?**

Search engines lead me to other Postgresql doc about the `pg_dump` with exactly the same explanation.

Comment: This is documented in the manual for `pg_dump`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html see the part about the `--section` argument

Comment: ok in the part` --schema-only` it explains: --section=pre-data and --section=post-data together are similar to --schema-only, that is the kind of info I was looking for. But the part `--section` argument of the "classic" doc has the same content as in the PGadmin 4 doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [official doc](http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) there is the best explanation I found: In the part`--schema-only` it states that: `--section=pre-data` and `--section=post-data` together are similar to `--schema-only`.

Answer (score 14):

If you try to make two backups of the same object and using `--section=pre-data` for the first one and `--section=post-data` for the second one, you will see that:

`pre-data` contains all information related to table/schema definition, sequences, owner and settings

`post-data` contains all the constraints information.

Comment: This should be included in official docs.  What exists is too nebulous to be useful.  Docs do a nice job explaining "post-data", which is indexes, constraints, etc... basically stuff you create after the tables exist.